# Windows Phone 8.1, universal app, How to profiling background task

Tags: windows-phone-8, profiling, win-universal-app

Hi I've created an app with a background task but I can't figure out how to profiling (memory and cpu) I've already tried this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn641982.aspx but only works with foreground app...

My needs is to profiling cpu and memory

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the Performance Monitor / Performance Recorder that comes with Visual Studio. Details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629255.aspx